# Branching from deleted path in svn

Tags: svn, branch

I want to create a branch off a revision that "doesn't exist".  What I have so far:

("/branches" is shorthand for "http://mysvn/myrep/branches)

1. /branches/1.0.x has revs 1-24900
2. I want /branches/myBranch to be at 24900 so I copy the /1.0.x
3. I want /branches/1.0.x to be at 24887 so I delete it in preparation for...
4. svn cp /branches/myBranch:24887 /branches/1.0.x

Which then complains that

> svn: Path
>   'http://mysvn/myrep/branches/myBranch:24887'
>   does not exist in revision 24901

Is there a way I can do this on the server? I really don't like checking out my entire branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into "Peg revisions": http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html

In short, try

```
svn cp /branches/myBranch@24887 /branches/1.0.x
```

i.e., replace the colon with '@'.

Comment: ...except that you need to change /branches/myBranch@24887 to /branches/1.0.x@24887 - as myBranch only existed at revision 24901 (24900 being the last commit of 1.0.x prior to starting this mess). 

e.g. the @rev must be used against the url that actually had that revision...

Comment: Ah, the last revision of 1.0.x was in r100, so you'll probably use "svn cp /branches/myBranch@100 /branches/1.0.x".

Comment: oops - I modified my original post to have more realistic version numbers (e.g. a large repository rather than a small one) - our checkouts take many minutes as opposed to many seconds.  I'll update the outstanding mis-edit

Answer (score 2):

You need to take advantage of peg revisions.  Here's the chapter in the SVN book:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html